# Sources for Incantations outside of UA?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic, rituals, d20-modern

Are there any sources for [Incantations](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/magic/incantations.htm) or rituals outside of Unearthed Arcana or Urban Arcana?

I find the system fascinating, but there are relatively few to choose from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Relics and Rituals](http://www.rpg.net/reviews/archive/classic/rev_3799.phtml) by [Sword and Sorcery](http://www.white-wolf.com/). Chapter III of the book is entitled Ritual Magic and Chapter IV is entitled True Rituals. An excerpt:

> Beyond the dusty books and the quick gestures and the sonorous words
>   that convey the power of spellcasters, there exists another level, one
>   that rewards an even deeper understanding of magic. Most magicians and
>   priests remain content to wield the power that they initially learn
>   to control. Some spellcasters explore the subtle changes that they can
>   exercise through metamagic feats, learning the truth beyond the
>   magical tapestry and drawing upon even more powerful effects.
>
> Beyond even these initial explorations, there is ritual magic.
>
> Ritual magic can be broken down into three aspects: augmented ritual
>   casting, combined ritual casting, and true rituals. Ritual magic is
>   available to both divine and arcane casters within the scope of their
>   training. The use of augmented and combined ritual casting is referred
>   to as "ritual casting" of a spell, as these two types of ritual magic
>   are used to augment a caster's normal repertoire of spells. Clerics
>   may therefore apply ritual casting to the converted spontaneous
>   casting of cure or inflict spells.
>
> True rituals are entirely new "spells" that must be learned or
>   researched individually in order for their power to be harnessed. Due
>   to the exacting nature of preparing true rituals, they are only
>   available to clerics, druids and wizards.
>
> Since all ritualistic magic involves longer casting times and is much
>   flashier in respects to casting techniques, opponents get a +4 bonus
>   to all Spot and Listen checks against the caster(s) during the casting
>   of any type of ritual.

Comment: This is a pretty good resource. Not quite what I was looking for (it's a different subsystem, and requires casting), but still useful.

Comment: @Arkhaic Yes, it isn't exactly the same, but, like you, I had scoured a lot of different books I had in previous years to help support the idea. Whenever a player (I usually just DM now) wants to do rituals, I use the appropriate knowledge rank (applicable to the type of casting) as their caster level for that particular ritual (using that resource). Simple house rule that could expand a lot more of the ritualistic and incantation type of spellcasting.